# $Q_3$ is symmetric with respect to the $\sigma_v$ operation?

Tags: molecular-structure, symmetry, group-theory, ir-spectroscopy

I am currently studying the textbook *Infrared and Raman Spectroscopy: Principles and Spectral Interpretation*, second edition, by Peter J. Larkin. Section **8. Symmetry: Infrared and Raman Active Vibrations**, says the following:

> Fig. 2.15 shows the Cartesian displacement vectors (arrows) of the vibrational modes $Q_1$, $Q_2$, and $Q_3$ of the bent triatomic $\ce{XY2}$ molecule (such as water), and shows how they are modified by the symmetry operations $C_2$, $\sigma_v$, and $\sigma^\prime_v$. For nondegenerate modes of vibration such as these, the displacement vectors in the first column (the identity column, $I$) are multiplied by either (+1) or (-1) as shown to give the forms in the other three columns. Multiplication by (+1) does not change the original form so the resulting form is said to be symmetrical with respect to that symmetry operation. Multiplication by (-1) reverses all the vectors of the original form and the resulting form is said to be antisymmetrical with respect to that symmetry element. As seen in Fig. 2.15, $Q_1$ and $Q_2$ are both totally symmetric modes (i.e., symmetric to all symmetry operations), whereas $Q_3$ is symmetric with respect to the $\sigma^\prime_v$ operation but anti-symmetric with respect to the $C_2$ and $\sigma_v$ operations.
> [image]
> [image]

It is this part that concerns me:

> As seen in Fig. 2.15, $Q_1$ and $Q_2$ are both totally symmetric modes (i.e., symmetric to all symmetry operations), whereas $Q_3$ is symmetric with respect to the $\sigma^\prime_v$ operation but anti-symmetric with respect to the $C_2$ and $\sigma_v$ operations.

Shouldn't it say that $Q_3$ is symmetric with respect to the $\sigma_v$ operation, since this is the same form, and anti-symmetric with respect to the $C_2$ and $\sigma_v$ operations? It seems like a typo to me.

I would greatly appreciate it if people would please take the time to clarify this.

Comment: $\sigma'$  is in the plane of the image and molecule so Q3 is symmetric wrt this but not with respect to the other operations. (Note that some point group tables may define $\sigma,\sigma'$ the other way round.)

Comment: @porphyrin I don't understand. The author says the following: "Multiplication by (+1) does not change the original form so the resulting form is said to be symmetrical with respect to that symmetry operation. Multiplication by (-1) reverses all the vectors of the original form and the resulting form is said to be antisymmetrical with respect to that symmetry element." For $Q_3$, multiplication by (+1) results in the same form, and this happens under the $\sigma_v$ symmetry operation.

Comment: the $\sigma_v'$ rectangle on the Q1 image (top tight) has the wrong perspective for C2v it should be in the plane of the paper, I did not notice this before (: It should be drawn as in image  D.

Comment: @porphyrin Do you mean $C_2$ or $\sigma^\prime_v$? You wrote $Q_1$, but then wrote both $\sigma^\prime_v$ and $C_2v$, so it's not clear what you are referring to. Also, this misses my point: For $Q_3$, it is **only** the symmetry operation $\sigma_v$ that results in multiplication by (+1) and therefore the same form, so shouldn't the author be saying that $Q_3$ is symmetric with respect to only the $\sigma_v$ operation, and anti-symmetric with respect to the $C_2$ and $\sigma^\prime_v$ operations?

Comment: Q3 is antisym wrt C$_2$ and $\sigma_v$ and symmetric wrt $\sigma'_v$  as the atoms remain in the plane of the page (as it were) and this is also the plane of $\sigma_v'$ even though the image at the top right of Q1 indicates otherwise. The $\sigma_v$ plane projects out of the page towards the viewer. Q3 should have B2 sym species so the last two labels are wrong $\sigma_v (-1) \;\sigma_v' (+1)$

Comment: @porphyrin Ok, if the labels are wrong then that what the author said would make sense. Thanks for the clarification.